# How to store data in array in loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to have data whose format should be something like this:

```
{"parent":
   {"class":"Green","user_name":"Nitish","user_loc":"Delhi","user_id":1,"user_blockclass":null,
      "child":[
           {"class":"Green","user_name":null,"user_loc":null,"user_id":1,"user_blockclass":"fst",
              "child":[
                          {"class":"Green","user_name":"pandey","user_loc":"sdgfsjd","user_id":6,"user_blockclass":"fst"},
                          {"class":"Green","user_name":"chaku","user_loc":"sdgjs","user_id":7,"user_blockclass":"snd"},
                          {"class":"Green","user_name":"iks","user_loc":"sjkdfhkjs","user_id":8,"user_blockclass":"trd"},
                          {"class":"Green","user_name":"yash","user_loc":"hfksjdhfk","user_id":9,"user_blockclass":"frt"},
                          {"class":"Green","user_name":"joshi","user_loc":"dsfh","user_id":10,"user_blockclass":"fth"}
                       ]},
            {"class":"Green","user_name":null,"user_loc":null,"user_id":1,"user_blockclass":"snd",
                "child":[
                            {"class":"Green","user_name":"pandey","user_loc":"sdgfsjd","user_id":6,"user_blockclass":"fst"},
                            {"class":"Green","user_name":"chaku","user_loc":"sdgjs","user_id":7,"user_blockclass":"snd"},
                            {"class":"Green","user_name":"iks","user_loc":"sjkdfhkjs","user_id":8,"user_blockclass":"trd"},
                            {"class":"Green","user_name":"yash","user_loc":"hfksjdhfk","user_id":9,"user_blockclass":"frt"},
                            {"class":"Green","user_name":"joshi","user_loc":"dsfh","user_id":10,"user_blockclass":"fth"}
                        ]},
        ]
}
```

Each element will contain 5 child elements and each child element will contain 5 child elements respectively. Now I'm trying to push data into array:

```
public function viewplans(Request $request)
{
    $selectplan = $request->selectplan;
    $user = Auth::user();
    $userinfo= [];
    $userinfo['class'] = "Green";
    $userinfo['user_name'] = $user->name;
    $userinfo['user_loc'] = $user->city;
    $userinfo['user_id'] = $user->id;
    if($selectplan == 1)
    {                                   
        $blockclass = ['fst', 'snd', 'trd', 'frt', 'fth'];            
        $children = $user->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
        $subuserinfo = [];
        $subsubuserinfo = [];
        for($i = 0; $i <5; $i++)
        {

          if($children[$i])
          {
            $subuser = User::findOrFail($children[$i]->pivot->child);
            $subuserinfo['class'] = "Green";
            $subuserinfo['user_name'] = $subuser->name;
            $subuserinfo['user_loc'] = $subuser->city;
            $subuserinfo['user_id'] = $subuser->id;
            $subuserinfo['user_blockclass'] = $blockclass[$i];
            $subchildren = $subuser->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
            for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
            {

                if($subchildren[$j]){
                  $subsubuser = User::findOrFail($subchildren[$j]->pivot->child);
                  $subsubuserinfo['class'] = "Green";
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_name'] = $subsubuser->name;
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_loc'] = $subsubuser->city;
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_id'] = $subsubuser->id;
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_blockclass'] = $blockclass[$j];
                  $subuserinfo['child'][$j] = $subsubuserinfo;
                }
                else
                {
                  $subsubuserinfo['class'] = "Black";
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_name'] = 'No User';
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_loc'] = 'No Loc';
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_id'] = 'No ID';
                  $subsubuserinfo['user_blockclass'] = $blockclass[$j];
                  $subuserinfo['child'][$j] = $subsubuserinfo;
                }
            }
            $userinfo['child'][$i] = $subuserinfo;                                                                    
          }
          else
          {
              $subsubuserinfo['class'] = "Black";
              $subsubuserinfo['user_name'] = 'No User';
              $subsubuserinfo['user_loc'] = 'No Loc';
              $subsubuserinfo['user_id'] = 'No ID';
              $subsubuserinfo['user_blockclass'] = $blockclass[$i];
              $userinfo['child'][$i] = $subuserinfo;
          }
        }
        $tree = $userinfo;
//      dd($tree);
        return view('member.5matrix', [
          'tree' => ($tree),
          'blockclass' => $blockclass
        ]);
    }
}
```

Even if the data is not available it should store the else value. Currently I'm getting error:

> Undefined offset: 2

Help me out in having proper format of data as it is mentioned in JSON format.

Comment: On what line is this error?

Comment: @u_mulder I'm using larvael framework. It is showing `ErrorException in Collection.php line 1288:
Undefined offset: 2`

Comment: The best solution is to first fetch all the relevant records with their parent_id (or none).
You need an array {[parent_id => [child_id, child_id],....etc}
Then create a separate function to do what you do repeatedly now. 
Pass the parent_children array and the current parent_id

Start with all the true parents (parent[0][]) , take care to give this a separate index, as NULL cannot be used as an index I believe.
Loop through the children, and then in that function, you can recursively call back the function, passing the parent[current_child_id][children]
Plus an array with all nodes...

Comment: You need only one query with my explaination above. Even if you need to fetch a little more records this outperforms the separate query solution.

Comment: @twicejr: Let me try out. Thanks for update!

Comment: You shall need to do what I told you in the view, probably... I'd just create a function in the view doing what I said. If it is possible in laravel I don't know, otherwise maybe use a litte php-glue instead :)

Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only places in the code you've shown that could be causing the "undefined offset: 2" error are

```
$subuser = User::findOrFail($children[$i]->pivot->child);
```

or

```
$subsubuser = User::findOrFail($subchildren[$j]->pivot->child);
```

Everywhere else that uses an integer (`$i` or `$j`) as an array key is either setting a value at that key, which won't cause an undefined offset error (it will just create the key if it doesn't exist), or referencing `$blockclass`, which has enough elements that your `for` loop won't exceed its length.

This means that for whatever reason, either

```
$children = $user->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
```

or

```
$subchildren = $subuser->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
```

isn't returning as many items as you're expecting it to. (More specifically, it seems it's only returning two items instead of five.)

There are probably other ways to do it, but if you want to keep doing it the way you are currently, you'll need to add checks that `$children[$i]` and `$subchildren[$j]` are set before you use them, and add your default values if they aren't.

`if ($subuser) {...` and `if ($subsubuser) {...` check that those variables are set, but you're actually getting the error at the time you're trying to set them. I think you could actually combine the `findOrFail` call with the check for `$children[$i]` and `$subchildren[$j]` inside the `if` condition:

```
if (isset($children[$i]) && $subuser = User::findOrFail($children[$i]->pivot->child)) {
```

Comment: That's why I'm using `If else` statement  `$subsubuser = User::findOrFail($subchildren[$j]->pivot->child);
                if($subsubuser){....}` do I need to have another check?

Comment: Both the places I tried `if($children[$i])` and `if($subchildren[$j])' still I'm getting same.

Comment: Yes, `if($children[$i])` still depends on `$children[$i]` being set. It's just evaluating it as a boolean. You'll need to use `isset` instead to avoid the undefined offset error.

Comment: That solved my problem, but only thing I'm facing is, it is storing repetitive values, also I have else statement which stores a default value if the object/data is not present. But it ain't getting there.

Comment: That's strange. You're not getting the `if` _or_ the `else` values? For the `$subuser` level, or the `$subsubuser` level?

Comment: I'm getting for `$subuser` level, but not getting `$subsubuser` level. It is all repetitive.

Comment: It was a silly mistake of iterating variable. Thanks a lot for your help... :)